# Отправка фото ботом телеграм

Tags: telegram, бот, aiogram

подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать отправку фото пайтон aiogram, пример моего кода:

```
await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, ..)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.from_user.id, photo=open('photo.jpg', 'rb'), caption='описание фото(текстовое сообщение ) до 1024 символов')

Или вместо open можете указать file_id если фото уже было загружено в телеграм.